# No puedo colocar imagen de fondo con CSS, background-image, no lo reconoce

Tags: css, imagen

```css
input:focus{
     background-color: #58ACFA;
     color: #000000;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    body {     
        background-size: 100vw 100vh;
        font-family: arial;
        background-image: url("img/sea.jpeg");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        margin:0;  
    }
    
    form {
     width: 400px;
     margin:auto;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
         
       </head>
       <body>
          <header>
             
            
          </header>
           
          <form action="">
              <h1> Registration Form </h1>
             <p> The required fields are with * </p>
             <fieldset>
               <legend>  Contact information </legend> 
             <label for="firstName">FirstName (*) </label><input type="text" id="firstName" required minlength="3" maxlength="40" >
             
             <label for="lastName">LastName (*)  </label><input type="text" id="lastName" required minlength="3" maxlength="40" >
            
             <label for="email">Email (*) </label><input type="email" id="email" size="25" maxlength="100" required  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}">
             </fieldset>
             <br>
    
             <fieldset>
                <legend> Registration information</legend>
    
             <div>
                <label for="bday">Birthday</label>
                <input type="date" id="bday"  >
             </div>
       <fieldset>
            <legend>Sports practice? </legend>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes"> Yes</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="no" value="no"> No </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sometimes" value="sometimes"> Sometimes</label>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Comparte una captura en dónde se aprecie la ruta en dónde se encuentra la imagen y el archivo del código, para ver si es problema de la url o del nombre del archivo.

Comment: Abriste la consola del navegador y verificaste que la ruta de la imagen esta bien y no esta dando un 404?

Answer (score 1):

He hecho pruebas con tu código y aparentemente el problema que tienes es con la imagen. Verifica si estás poniendo bien la ruta al cargarla desde `background-image`.

Cambiando la imagen, en tú código, si se me mostraba de `background` en el `body`.

Answer (score 0):

intenta poniendo el background directamente en el body es decir tu archivo html asi:

```
 <body style=" background-image: url("img/sea.jpeg");">
```

si esto funciona y estas usando localhost refresca la pagina limpiando el capcha  ctrl+f5 a ver si la capcha del navegador esta interrupiendo en algo, no es una solucion de codigo pero es una alternativa.

ahora si no funciona verifica que la ruta este bien por que con eso bastaria

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado la ruta de tu imagen por una online y funciona, por lo que lo más seguro es que sea un problema de url o de transcripción.

Demo con el cambio únicamente en la url de la imagen:

```css
input:focus{
     background-color: #58ACFA;
     color: #000000;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    body {     
        background-size: 100vw 100vh;
        font-family: arial;
        background-image: url("http://picsum.photos/1400/850?image=949");
        background-attachment: fixed;
        margin:0;  
    }
    
    form {
     width: 400px;
     margin:auto;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
         
       </head>
       <body>
          <header>
             
            
          </header>
           
          <form action="">
              <h1> Registration Form </h1>
             <p> The required fields are with * </p>
             <fieldset>
               <legend>  Contact information </legend> 
             <label for="firstName">FirstName (*) </label><input type="text" id="firstName" required minlength="3" maxlength="40" >
             
             <label for="lastName">LastName (*)  </label><input type="text" id="lastName" required minlength="3" maxlength="40" >
            
             <label for="email">Email (*) </label><input type="email" id="email" size="25" maxlength="100" required  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}">
             </fieldset>
             <br>
    
             <fieldset>
                <legend> Registration information</legend>
    
             <div>
                <label for="bday">Birthday</label>
                <input type="date" id="bday"  >
             </div>
       <fieldset>
            <legend>Sports practice? </legend>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes"> Yes</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="no" value="no"> No </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sometimes" value="sometimes"> Sometimes</label>
        </fieldset>
```